# Scipy - adjust National Team means based on sample size

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, bayesian, statistical-test

I have a population of National Teams (32), and parameter (mean) that I want to measure for each team, aggregated per match.

For example: I get the mean scouts for all strikers for each team, per match, and then I get the the mean (or median) for all team matches.

---

Now, one group of teams have played 18 matches and another group has played only 8 matches for the World Cup Qualifying.

I have an hypothesis that, for two teams with equal mean value, the one with larger sample size (18) should be ranked higher.

---

```
less_than_8 = all_stats[all_stats['games']<=8]
```

I get values:

```
3     0.610759
7     0.579832
14    0.537579
20    0.346510
25    0.403606
27    0.536443
```

and with:

```
sns.displot(less_than_8, x="avg_attack",kind='kde',bw_adjust=2)
```

I plot:

[image]

with a mean of `0.5024547681196802`

---

Now, for:

```
more_than_18 = all_stats[all_stats['games']>=18]
```

I get values:

```
0     0.148860
1     0.330585
4     0.097578
6     0.518595
8     0.220798
11    0.200142
12    0.297721
15    0.256037
17    0.195157
18    0.176994
19    0.267094
21    0.295228
22    0.248932
23    0.420940
24    0.148860
28    0.297721
30    0.350516
31    0.205128
```

and I plot the curve:

[image]

with a lower mean, of `0.25982701104003497`.

---

It seems clear that sample size does affect the mean, diminishing it as size increases.

Is there a way I can adjust the means of larger sample size AS IF they were being calculated on a smaller sample size, or vice versa, using prior and posteriori assumptions?

NOTE. I have std for all teams.

---

There is a proposed solution for a similar matter, using Empirical Bayes estimation and a beta distribution, which can be seen here [Understanding empirical Bayes estimation (using baseball statistics)](http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/), but I'm not sure as to how it could prior means could be extrapolated from successful attempts.

Comment: I think this question is better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ My personal understanding is that increasing sample size doesn't affect the mean monotonically - only that it will bring it closer to the population mean.

Answer (score 0):

Sample size does affect the mean, but it's not exactly like mean should increase or decrease when sample size is increased. Moreover; sample size will get closer and closer to the **population mean μ and standard deviation σ**.

I cannot give an exact proposal without more information like; how many datapoints per team, per match, what are the standard deviations in these values. But just looking at the details I have to presume the 6 teams qualified with only 8 matches somehow smashed whatever the stat you have measured. (Probably this is why they only played 8 matches?)

I can make a few simple proposals based on the fact that you would want to rank these teams;

Proposal 1:

1. Extend these stats and calculate a population mean, std for a season. (If you have prior seasons use them as well)
2. Use this mean value to rank teams (Without any sample adjustments) - This would likely result in the 6 teams landing on top

Proposal 2:

1. Calculate per game mean across all teams(call it `mean_gt`) [ for game 01. mean for game 02..  or mean for game in Week 01, Week 02 ] - I recommend based on week as 6 teams will only have 8 games and this would bias datapoints in the beginning or end.
2. plot `mean_gt` and compare each team's given Week's mean with mean_gt [ call this diff `diff_gt`]
3. `diff_gt` gives a better perspective of a team's performance on each week. So you can get a mean of this value to rank teams.
   **When filling datapoint for 6 teams with 8 matches I suggest using the population mean rather than extrapolating to keep things simple.**
   **But it's possible to get creative; like using the difference of aggregate total for 32 teams also. Like `[ 32*mean_gt_of_week_1 - total of [32-x] teams]/x`**

I do have another idea. But rather wait for a feedback as I am way off the simple solution for adjusting a sample mean. :)

Comment: Thank you. Mean values above are alredy sampled from matches. I get the mean for each match, and the values you see above are means of means, over all matches. In my dataset I also have std calculated over all matches

Comment: You mean the original dataset is not available to you?   
To implement my second proposal (which I believe is a very fair metric to rank all teams in one scale) its mandatory to have each teams game by game performance values. Sadly if you only have means of  teams I fear the maximum you can try to do is some extrapolation. Results would probably duplicate.

Comment: per match are values aggregated from individual PLAYERS. and then TEAM means are calculated for the number of matches

Comment: Sorry about the delay. But this means you are able to follow the path I proposed in the second section. Have you attempted it?